# DecimalFormatter with thousands separator 0 value returning .00

Tags: java, string-formatting, decimalformat

I have a problem formatting on my result on the android app.

I'm using a `DecimalFormat` with a format of `"###,###.00"`. now, The big number `100000.0` returning `100,000.00` which is correct. but when I parse `0`  the result is only `.00`. How can I make it `0.00`.

Note: I have tried to use `String.format` extending `("%.2f",value)` but the problem is when it reach the 10000.0 amount, it returns 10,0000.00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the format of `"###,###.00"` to

```
"###,##0.00"
```

When you use `#` that makes it optional, when you use `0` it is required.